# Why my redux-saga is async

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

In my React-Native app I write a user log in component which send username and hash to server, compare hash with hash in database and return a result. I implemented that `using redux-saga`:

```
function* fetchUser(action) {
  try {
    const user = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action);
    yield put({type: types.USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED, user});
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({type: types.USER_FETCH_FAILED, message: e.message});
  }
}

export function* watchFetchUser() {
  yield* takeEvery(types.USER_FETCH_REQUESTED, fetchUser);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield fork(watchFetchUser);
  // ...
}
```

And I expect that `const user` will contain response from API and after will run `yield put({type: types.USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED, user})`. But after `yield call(Api.fetchUser, action)` `user` is `undefined`. But `Api.fetchUser` returns right response.

And I can't find where is my mistake. Why result of `const user = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action)` is `undefined` when after `Api.fetchUser` return correct response?

```
fetchUser(action) {
    const url = `${apiUrls.LOGIN_URL}`;

    fetch(url, 'POST', action.user)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => res)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the promise from the fetchUser function. It should be

```
fetchUser(action) {
    const url = `${apiUrls.LOGIN_URL}`;

    return fetch(url, 'POST', action.user)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => res)
  }
```